# Proving continuity of a monotonous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $I$ be an interval and a function $f$ $:$ $I$ $\to$ $R$ is differentiable on $I$. If $f'$ be monotonic on $I$ prove that $f'$ is continuous on $I$.)

I wanted to solve this first for an increasing function. Let $c$ $\in$ $(a,b)$. Since $f$ is differentiable on $c$, $lim_{x\to c}$ ${f(x) - f(c)\over x - c}$ $=$ $f'(c)$.
Now I can't understand how to proceed . Is there any way to solve this problem by Mean Value Theorem or Rolle's Theorem ? Please help.

Comment: You don't need that $f$ is monotone; every differentiable function is continuous.

Comment: How can I show that $f'$ is also differentiable ?? @Hanul Jeon

Comment: Uh, I misread your question. You may get a hint from the [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)), which says that every derivative of a differentiable function satisfies the intermediate value theorem, even if it is not continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $f^{'}$ is monotonic the discontinuities of $f^{'}$ (if they exist)  are  only jump discontinuities.

Again $f^{'}$ also satisfies Intermediate Value Property.

And the above two can't happen together.Hence $f^{'}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

[Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)) is the main key to prove your problem. Therefore, we know that $f'$ satisfies the intermediate value property.

Now assume that $f'$ is increasing. If $f'$ is discontinuous at $a$, then it has a left limit and right limit, which are different. How to derive a contraposition from the intermediate value property of $f'$? (Hint. Let $p<a<q$. Find $l\in (f'(p), f'(q))$ which is not taken by $f'$.)